# Make a popup form in AngularJs and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, rest, popup, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm newbie in Angular and Node, so I don't know a lot of it.

I have an Angular single page and I want to create a popup form that appears when I click a button, and then send the information via rest to node. But I don't know how to do that. How can you do that??

Comment: Try angularStrap or AngularUI, either can create a modal with which you can submit a form

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal